# How to use a form to update a join relationship with a nested route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to go to a Restful route when adding/updating a join relationship.

I have the following controllers:

`home_controller, stores_controller, user_stores_controller (join table)`

With my simpleform, I am updating a user's favorite store (updating a join relationship). However, the route takes me the user_controller (which I don't have/didn't think I needed because devise is handling my users). I'm confused on what route to take. What route is more Restful and if my thinking is correct the route to create a user's favorite stores should be through the `users_stores_controller` with a Post path of `user/:user_id/stores`. Another possibility is update with a Patch path of `/user/:user_id/stores/:id` but I was unsure about this because I'm not just updating one store, a user can select multiple stores with the params attribute of `store_ids` will be passed

Or should I be updating the actually user using a user_controller with a Post path of `/user`?

What would the simple_form_for look like as well?

Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :stores, as: :check_boxes %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Update Favorite Stores", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Here are my models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_stores
  has_many :stores, through: :user_stores        
end

class UserStore < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :store
end

class Store < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_stores
  has_many :users, through: :user_stores
end
```

Here are my routes:

config/routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'

  resources :user do
    resources :stores
  end
end
```

Rails Routes

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)            devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)           devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                  devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                 devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                    devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                                        home#index
             user_stores GET    /user/:user_id/stores(.:format)          stores#index
                         POST   /user/:user_id/stores(.:format)          stores#create
          new_user_store GET    /user/:user_id/stores/new(.:format)      stores#new
         edit_user_store GET    /user/:user_id/stores/:id/edit(.:format) stores#edit
              user_store GET    /user/:user_id/stores/:id(.:format)      stores#show
                         PATCH  /user/:user_id/stores/:id(.:format)      stores#update
                         PUT    /user/:user_id/stores/:id(.:format)      stores#update
                         DELETE /user/:user_id/stores/:id(.:format)      stores#destroy
              user_index GET    /user(.:format)                          user#index
                         POST   /user(.:format)                          user#create
                new_user GET    /user/new(.:format)                      user#new
               edit_user GET    /user/:id/edit(.:format)                 user#edit
                    user GET    /user/:id(.:format)                      user#show
                         PATCH  /user/:id(.:format)                      user#update
                         PUT    /user/:id(.:format)                      user#update
                         DELETE /user/:id(.:format)                      user#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify url in simple form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, url: user_stores_path,  html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```